# Condition check for alphanumeric and numeric in ASP code

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, conditional-statements

Can anyone tell me how to put a check to check in a 6 digit value 5 digits can be alpha numeric but the 6th digit must be numeric in an ASP code using VB

Comment: Define "alphanumeric", for example is this "!$%^&9" valid?  If not then the currently accepted answer does not completely validate the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your value is fixed to 6 digits only, you can use **[Mid](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_mid.asp)** function. If your value is not fixed to 6 digits and you need to check the last digit, you can use **[Right](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_right.asp)** function with **[isNumeric](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_isnumeric.asp)** check.

for example:

```
<%
    is_numeric = isNumeric(Right(myValue,1))
%>
```

or

```
<%
    is_numeric = isNumeric(Mid(myValue,6,1))
%>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a regular expression, because you can check on both format and length, and you will be flexible if requirements change (like "change request: the last digit can not be zero")

```
str = "12aB34"
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
myRegExp.Pattern = "^[A-Z0-9]{5}\d$"
isValid = myRegExp.Test(str)    ' returns True in this case
```